# JavaScript Function to Pull related object fields

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am using the following query to try to pull fields off of a User lookup on the Account.  There is a field on the Account called Dedicated_Rep__c which is a user lookup.  I am building my button off the opportunity, and I want to be able to pull the Opportunity's Account's Dedicated Rep's First Name, Last Name, and Email.  Here's my code:

```
    function getDedicatedAccountRep (oppId) {
var result = sforce.connection.query("select Account.Id, Account.Dedicated_CS_Rep__r.FirstName from Opportunity where Id = '" + oppId + "' ");

if(!result || result['size'] != 1) { 
    return null;
    }

    var DedRepRole = result.getArray('records')[0];

    return DedRepRole.Account;
}

var dedicatedRep = getDedicatedAccountRep('{!Opportunity.Id}');
```

I am getting an error:

Cannot read property 'Dedicated_CS_Rep__c' of undefined

I am referencing the code later in the button and I am instantiating it by putting: dedicatedRep.Dedicated_CS_Rep__r.FirstName

Comment: Go to Setup, check the custom fields on Account, find that "Dedicated Rep" Check what's exactly the API name of the field - `Dedicated_Rep__c` or `Dedicated_CS_Rep__c`?

Comment: It's Dedicated_CS_Rep__c. So what I have in my code is correct. I'm wondering if there is an issue with my return statement. Right now it looks like I am return the Account.  Would I need to return the Dedicated_CS_Rep lookup instead?

Answer (score 0):

Start with something like that (I prefer the Google Chrome's javascript console, you can open it with Ctrl+Shift+J; but feel free to use Firefox + Firebug or IE's developer tools...)

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Account.Dedicated_CS_Rep__r.FirstName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}'");

console.log(result);
debugger;
```

This will let you inspect the query result and play with the results. I think your problem is that the full expression can look like this:

```
result.records.Account.Dedicated_CS_Rep__r.FirstName
```

A lot can go wrong here. `result` should be OK and `records` should be always 1 row since we run it for one Opportunity (let's ignore crazy scenarios where somebody deleted the Opp between you navigating to the page and clicking the button... But still:

- the `Account` can be blank (out of the box it's perfectly valid to have private Opportunities; maybe your organisation has marked the field as required).
- And similarly in theory it's valid to have Account without the user.

So - you have 2 chances to hit null pointer exception:

[image]

Therefore properly protected code would have this orgy of null / undefined checks:

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Account.Dedicated_CS_Rep__r.FirstName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}'");

console.log(result);

if(result != null 
    && result.records != null 
    && result.records.Account != null 
    && result.records.Account.Dedicated_CS_Rep__r != null){
    alert(result.records.Account.Dedicated_CS_Rep__r);
    // return result.records.Account.Dedicated_CS_Rep__r;
} else {
    alert('Nope');
    // return null;
}
```